# Can't remove ACE from directory

Tags: macos, acl

My applications folder has an ACE entry which prevents me from deleting its contents (not even as root, with sip disabled).
My problem is, that the command

`sudo chmod -N /Applications`

tells me, that I have no permission to do this.
I couldn't believe it and tried it in both single user and recovery mode, to no avail.

Output of `ls -leO`:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 148 root    admin  uappnd,nodump,opaque  4.9K Jul 31 08:55 Applications/
0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Is there any other possibility to fix this except from reinstalling the OS?

Comment: You're probably removing the wrong ACL - the /Applications one prevents you from deleting the entire directory - shouldn't you be looking at an ACL on a folder inside Applications?

Comment: The contents of the folder are, as far as I can tell not the culprit, they just have 777, 755, etc. with no ACL.

Answer (score 2):

The proper command to remove the ACE from the folder in SIP-disabled mode is:

```
sudo chmod -a "everyone deny delete" /Applications
```

You can also remove (or add) ACL entries by number/index:

```
sudo chmod -a# 0 /Applications
```

Comment: Yes, and the one I provided just removes all. My problem is not the command, but rather that I cant run it because of permission problems (ironically).

Comment: @redxef While you're sorting things out `sudo -s` might be easier to be sure you're root in the shell. Also - what does `ls -leO /` with the capital O show and `spctl --status`? You might need to add those to the body of your question or ask a follow on question - the answer above works to remove ACL for me.

Comment: @redxef BTW for me your command works properly even after adding arbitrary additional ACEs (in ElCap though)

Comment: `spctl --status` returned `enabled`, I disabled it with `--master-disable`, which still doesn't solve the problem. I added the output of `ls -leO`, as you suggested.

Comment: Roman-Mac-Mini-M1.local ➜  ~  sudo chmod -a# 0 Pictures
chmod: No ACL present 'Pictures'
Roman-Mac-Mini-M1.local ➜  ~  sudo rm -R Pictures
rm: Pictures: Operation not permitted
Roman-Mac-Mini-M1.local ➜  ~  sudo chmod -a "everyone deny delete"  Pictures
chmod: No ACL present 'Pictures'
Roman-Mac-Mini-M1.local ➜  ~  sudo rm -R Pictures
rm: Pictures: Operation not permitted

Any ideas?